# Write on other sharepoint site using webserivces

Tags: c#, sharepoint, workflow, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-workflow

I have 2 Sharepoint 2013 sites. 
When user adding new item in SPList at first SPSite -> starting workflow, what must added copy of item in SPList at second SPSite. This is my code:

```
   public void UpdateSPList(string Title)
        {
            using (AuthenticationSvc.Authentication authSvc = new AuthenticationSvc.Authentication())
            {
                    try
                    {
                        using (ListsSvc.Lists list = new ListsSvc.Lists())
                        {
                            list.Url = @"http://second-srharepoint-site.com/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx";
                            list.CookieContainer = new System.Net.CookieContainer();
                            list.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
                            list.PreAuthenticate = true;

                            list.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("domain\\username", "password");


                            string strBatch = "<Method Cmd='New'><Field Name='Title'>" + Title + "</Field> ";

                            XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
                            XmlElement elBatch = xmlDoc.CreateElement("Batch");
                            elBatch.SetAttribute("OnError", "Continue");

                            elBatch.InnerXml = strBatch;
                            XmlNode ndReturn = list.UpdateListItems("SPListName", elBatch);   


                        }
                    }
                    finally
                    {

                    }

            }

        }
```

But on line `elBatch.InnerXml = strBatch;` I get exception:

> - $exception {"Unexpected end of file has occurred. The following elements are not closed: Method. Line 1, position 60."}
>     System.Exception {System.Xml.XmlException}

I don't know how fix this problem. Help me, please.

Comment: The XML string is invalid. You need to add closing elements for *all* elements, not only the last

Comment: Why aren't you using CSOM anyway? You could simply update the Name Title property as you would with any other ORM or OData client. The asmx web services were deprecated back in 2010, so your code is problematic by definition.

Comment: I don't know how do it better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the string isn't valid XML because the closing `Method` element is missing. It should be

```
"<Method Cmd='New'><Field Name='Title'>" + Title + "</Field></Method>"
```

Second, the ASMX services were deprecated back in 2010. You shouldn't use them for any king of development, especially against SP 2013. The client-side object model (CSOM) is *a lot* simpler and easier to use. There are [a lot](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179912.aspx) of examples in the documentation. The snippet that creates a new item is :

```
// Starting with ClientContext, the constructor requires a URL to the 
// server running SharePoint. 
ClientContext context = new ClientContext("http://SiteUrl"); 

// Assume that the web has a list named "Announcements". 
List announcementsList = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Announcements"); 

// We are just creating a regular list item, so we don't need to 
// set any properties. If we wanted to create a new folder, for 
// example, we would have to set properties such as 
// UnderlyingObjectType to FileSystemObjectType.Folder. 
ListItemCreationInformation itemCreateInfo = new ListItemCreationInformation(); 
ListItem newItem = announcementsList.AddItem(itemCreateInfo); 
newItem["Title"] = "My New Item!"; 
newItem["Body"] = "Hello World!"; 
newItem.Update(); 

context.ExecuteQuery();
```

No XML fiddling, you simply create a new item, set its properties and call Update

Comment: I take `+ ex {"The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized."} System.Exception {System.Net.WebException}` when write you code after  `list.Credentials...` . How fix it? Thank you.